# Setting up an IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

I need some help here. I have a website in asp.net and a database in my local machine, and I'm setting up a testing enviroment so that I can access the site and the database from outside the local network and make tests. I want to set up a server in my windows 10 using IIS to publish the site, and I already know how to publish a asp.net site through Visual Studio and IIS manager. My only issue now is to make it available outside my network. Is there a easier way of doing this than having to buy a domain and a hosting service?

Comment: Some ISPs allow you to open your router to outside traffic, but generally this is a horrible idea for security. Your issue has nothing to do with IIS or Windows 10. I suggest you change the question title to "How to deploy a web application on my local machine to be accessible by www?" or "Where can I find free hosting services?"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a free azure app:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/#app-service1

You can run a single website (asp.net) and not need to register a domain it will give you a link publicly available on the web.

Whoops, sorry, the database wouldn't be free however the basic version is not expensive. This is in fact what I run for my own test cases.

In order to host at home, you would need to ensure that you had a static IP address and that port 80 was opened to allow traffic in and out.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1058/how-do-i-set-up-a-web-server-out-of-my-home

Comment: How do you they're using a database that would require payment as opposed to [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) or [LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB)?

Comment: fair question. quick answer is I don't.